# How to run a trigger on existing rows

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-performance

I have a process that inserts records into a table.

The table is defined with a trigger like this ...

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrig AFTER INSERT ON myTable FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE myProcedure();
```

The process that does the `INSERT` into myTable is outside of my control, it basically just spews records into the table throughout the day 24/7.

The functionality in `myProcedure()` requires database resources. During busy periods the rate that records arrive is greater than the database can cope with (about 500 records per second is the limit). If I disable the trigger using `ALTER TABLE myTable DISABLE TRIGGER myTrig`  then the system can cope with maybe 1000 records per second.

I can then re-enable the trigger when the system isn't as busy, but obviously those records added whilst the trigger was disabled won't have been processed correctly.

Is there any way to re-run the trigger on selected records ALREADY in the table?

My current best guess is that during busy periods I should divert incoming records to a copy of `myTable` thats identical to the original (but without the trigger) and then when the system quiets down later I can insert from the copy, back to the original where they should be processed by the trigger (albeit later than they should have been)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trigger function requires the triggering action. When triggered `FOR EACH ROW` it also typically needs the triggering row as input. But a plain function can replay almost anything a trigger function does.

The best course of action depends on **whether the trigger function `myProcedure()` alters the inserted row** itself.

**If so**, your idea with a separate, staging table sounds good. A later `UPDATE` would write a new row version anyway. So it's efficient overall to write to a staging table first and `INSERT` into the target table later. If it's acceptable to lose data in case of a server crash, you might even use an [`UNLOGGED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) table  for that, and cope with even more rows per second.
The eventual `INSERT` to the main table will also fire the trigger, all done.

**If not** (and if an `UNLOGGED` table isn't an option anyway), I would write to the destination table directly. Everything the trigger function does can now be replayed with a plain function. If you can't duplicate the functionality of the trigger function, the next best idea would be to write to a copy of `myTable`, with the same trigger on it. Only make it `RETURN NULL;` instead of `RETURN NEW;` to skip the triggering row itself. (So nothing is written to the copy.)

If you can't or won't make a modified copy of the trigger function, alternatively add another trigger on the temp table like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trg_cancel_insert()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
RETURN NULL;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER zzz_last_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON pg_temp.myTable_copy  -- the copy!
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.trg_cancel_insert();
```

This also skips the triggering insert itself. But everything that's executed in `myProcedure()` from the earlier trigger still sticks.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html#id-1.9.3.93.6)

> If multiple triggers of the same kind are defined for the same event, they will be fired in alphabetical order by name.

Comment: I think I'll go with a staging table - thanks for the tip about UNLOGGED, I wasn't aware of this option.